# How can I identify a PayPal user arriving at the return URL for a subscription with a free trial?

Tags: paypal, subscription, billing

With PayPal billing, with Auto Return and PDT enabled, when a user is returned to one's Return URL after a successful charge event, several parameters are appended by PayPal to the URL (e.g. "tx" for transaction id), which can then be used to identify the user.

However, if the user has just joined subscription with a free trial, no such information is appended and so the user is not identifiable at that point in time.

Since IPN is asynchronous, the IPN notification may arrive too late so one cannot rely on this.

Is there any way of identifying a user via the Return URL after they have entered a subscription with a free trial?

Answer (score 0):

Similar Que: [Implementation of free trial period with PayPal doesn't return any custom parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935914/implementation-of-free-trial-period-with-paypal-doesnt-return-any-custom-parame)

"If you are using PDT, then nothing will be sent back as no payment is taking place. Information will only be sent back if you are making a payment. I would recommend using IPN. Both the rm variable and PDT are dependent on the buyer returning back to your site. If the buyer does not return, such as their browser window unexpectedly crashes and closes, or they simply shut it no information will be sent back and it will be lost. This is why the rm variable and PDT are used more for creating dynamic receipts. IPN is more used for updating your system as it does not rely on the buyer returning back to your site. "

"Also with IPN you can resend the data to your system if you need to, and you can also view your IPN history from within your account. IPN usually takes place right after the payment is completed."