# Paypal Success page doesn't return any data for trial period subscription

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have included the PayPal library in my Codeigniter project.

[This Codexworld guide](https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-codeigniter) has helped me integrate PayPal with my project. Now, I have a subscription plan with the trial period. The PayPal success page doesn't return any data when I try to subscribe to the plan.

But, it does return transaction data if I do a checkout *without* a trial period.

**Notes:**

1) Am testing in sandbox

2) Found a similar question ([Implementation of free trial period with PayPal doesn't return any custom parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935914/implementation-of-free-trial-period-with-paypal-doesnt-return-any-custom-parame)) where nothing is returned

Answer (score 1):

When there is no transaction yet (such as with a trial period), no transaction data is returned. You can't expect to receive transaction data for something that does not exist.

If you want to query the status of the subscription, you need an API call for that, or to wait for the IPN.